# Proving conservation of energy (kinetic + potential) in classical mechanics for an arbitrary system of particles?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

For the case of a single particle in a potential $V$, it's simple :

${d\over dt} [{1 \over 2}mx(t)'^2 + V(x(t))] = mx(t)'x(t)'' - F(x(t))\ x(t)' = mx(t)'x(t)'' - mx(t)''x(t)' = 0$

But what about for a system of $N$ particles, with an arbitrary potential function $V$? Is there a direct way (i.e. not via Lagrangian formulation, etc.) of showing

${d\over dt} [\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{3}{1 \over 2}m_i x_{ij}(t)'^2 + V(x_{11}(t),x_{12}(t),x_{13}(t),x_{21}(t),..., x_{N1}(t),x_{N2}(t),x_{N3}(t)] = 0$

(Where $x_{i1},x_{i2},x_{i3}$ denote the x,y,z coordinates for each particle $i$)

?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is fairly simple. It is pretty much the same procedure as you did in the one-dimensional case, assuming that all the forces involved here can be derived from a potential function.

In the spirit of not giving away answers, here is a hint: $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{ij}} = F_{ij} = m_i \cdot x_{ij}(t)''$$
and by the chain rule for multivariable calculus, $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{3} \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{ij}} x_{ij}(t)'$$

I think you can figure out the answer based on these hints. Good luck!